# Calculate Running Increase of Number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting problem to solve of increasing a number by multiple percentages.

Let's say I have a widget and I want to increase the cost of this widget by percentages in a table.

WidgetPercent

```
WidgetID | Percent
---------+--------
1          .10
1          .06
```

Widget

```
WidgetID | Cost
---------+-------
1           100
```

I want to increase the cost of the widget by the first percent, then that total with the next percent and output a single value.

Example

```
100 * 1.10 = 110
110 * 1.06 = 116.60
```

Output should be 116.60. Results would be by WidgetID

I think I should use OVER (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with SUM but not quite sure in this context.

Note that the environment is SQL Server 2012 forward.

Comment: . . The second row should be 0.06, not 0.6.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a column to specify the order in which the percentages must be applied ?

Comment: edited, thank you Gordon

Comment: The order does not matter, as long as all the percents are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arithmetic like this:

```
select w.widgetid, w.cost * wp.factor
from (select widgetid, exp(sum(log(1 + percent))) as factor
      from widgetpercent wp
      group by widgetid
     ) wp join
     widget w
     on wp.widgetid = w.widgetid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61c2bafcbc746097c0ad82f2accc0104) is a db<>fiddle.